# Add a text "...Read more" in a specific part of UILabel IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to put this text "...Read more" when my label text is more than 3 lines, i want to prevent that my text will not be truncated.

I tried some code but i'm having problems with different iPhones widths, my code works on iPhone 6s, but doesn't on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s.

Here is my code:

```
let originalText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique ipsum non pretium mollis. Curabitur tristique asfhaksjf sfjhksafhdaf ahsdifhsadfh asdfhsahfoas sdofhasdhfasdf"

        label.text = originalText
        let labelWidth = label.frame.size.width * CGFloat(label.numberOfLines)

        let str = label.text! as NSString

        let words = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        var newStr = "" as NSString

        for word in words {
            let statement = "\(newStr) \(word) ... Read more" as NSString
            let size = statement.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: label.font])
            let readMoreStatement = " ... Read more" as NSString
            let sizeReadMore = readMoreStatement.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : label.font])

            if size.width < labelWidth {

                newStr = "\(newStr) \(word)"
                label.text = newStr as String
            } else {
                newStr = newStr.stringByAppendingString("... Read More")
                label.text = newStr as String
                break
            }
        }
```

Here is the result on 4s:

[image: Here is the result on 4s]

Here is the result on 6s:

[image: Here is the result on 6s]

Any suggestions how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to autoConstrains your label first and use the following code

```
  let originalText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique ipsum non pretium mollis. Curabitur tristique asfhaksjf sfjhksafhdaf ahsdifhsadfh asdfhsahfoas sdofhasdhfasdf"

    label.text = originalText
    print((label.text?.characters.count)!) 

    if (label.text?.characters.count)! < 100 { 

           label.text = originalText
           label.center  = view.center
           label.textAlignment = .justified 
           label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true // If you want a dynamic font size
           label.sizeToFit()
           print(label.text!) // If character count less then 100 approximately 3 lines
        } else {

            label.text = "...Read more"
            label.textAlignment = .center 
            print(label.text!) //If character count more then 100 exceeds 3 lines         

     // You can setup a UIButton here for your "...Read more" action

    }
```

Hope, this helps you....